# Problem with relationships (PHPMyAdmin) - added keys, not visible in relational view

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, relationship

I have a problem with the relationship between the tables in the database.
My database is the database of an online store.

The database includes such tables as:

- produkt (product)
- zamowienie (order)
- adres (address)
- klient (client)
- koszyk (basket)
- asortyment (assortment)
- kategoria (category)
- płatność (payment)

Adds foreign keys between them using the commands "alter table" and "add foreign key (id_xxx) REFERENCES name (id_xxx).
In the relational view, tables are not linked to others as I would like. You can see in the structure that the foreign key exists, but not in the graphic view.

[image: 1]

Comment: Don't use polish names in database. It's very bad practice.

Comment: @Tajni it would help if you gave some reason as to why it's bad practise and the issues it can raise

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite follow; are you saying that the graphical lines that are in the screenshot aren't correct? Or the Relation View tab is incorrect?